# Live Preview of my code doesn't work with css

Tags: html, css, file, cloud

I try to use live preview of my code.I installed the Five Server extention on VsCode but when I open the live preview the page doesn't allow the use of the css file

Google error (Ctrl + Shift +I>Console): "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/giann/OneDrive/%CE%A5%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AE%CF%82/code/code%20exercise/Exercise-6/styles/style.css"

I think that if I upload the file to a cloud service the page might recognise it but I don't know any

Comment: Above link translates to `file:///C:/Users/giann/OneDrive/Î¥ÏÎ¿Î»Î¿Î³Î¹ÏÏÎ®Ï/code/code exercise/Exercise-6/styles/style.css` Is that the folder where you left it?